# Retrieve objects inside json array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to retrieve team1 score however i cant seem to figure out how to output this. So far i've got this to work where $obj is the json output.

```
$obj->recent
```

JSON

```
"recent": [
    [
        {
        "match_id": "64886",
        "has_vods": false,
        "game": "dota2",
        "team 1": {
            "score": "",
            "name": "Wheel Whreck While Whistling",
            "bet": "7%"
        },
        "team 2": {
            "score": "",
            "name": "Evil Geniuses DotA2",
            "bet": "68%"
        },
        "live in": "1m 42s",
        "title": "Wheel Whreck... 7% vs 68% Evil...",
        "url": "",
        "tounament": "",
        "simple_title": "Wheel Whreck... vs Evil...",
        "streams": []
        }
]
```

Comment: `$obj = json_decode($json);` ?!

Comment: `$obj->recent[0][0]->{'team 1'}->score` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use json_decode(); This function returns proper object with arrays and objects inside. Now you need check what is an object and what is an array.

```
$obj = json_decode($obj, true);
$obj->recent; //array 
$obj->recent[0]; //first element of array
$obj->recent[0][0]; //first element of second array
$obj->recent[0][0]->{'team 1'}; //access to object team 1
$obj->recent[0][0]->{'team 1'}->score; //access to property of object team 1
```

You can find [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) helpful to understand what happens;

You can also check example on [json_decode documentation](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.json-decode.php#example-3489)

If you use var_dump function on $obj it will show you what is an array and what is an object.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `json_decode` to get that into an array. It looks like `recent` is an array of arrays of objects. So, you'll do something like

```
$json = json_decode($obj->recent, true);
$team1 = $json[0][0]['team 1']; //should return array
$score = $team1['score']
```

*edit*: Thanks for the comment, was missing a `true` as the second param in `json_decode`

Comment: if you don't pass true as the second parameter to json_decode the result is an object, not an array and this will throw errors.